# Subset delimited file by subset of one column

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a text file (call it `infile.txt`) where the columns have headers and are delimited by semicolons. A subset of it is reproduced below:

```
SCHCD;  SCHNAME
13110208001;    GOVT MIDSCHOOL 
10110208002;    GOVT HIGHSCHOOL 
21110208101;    MATRIC
21110208102;    UPPER SECONDARY
13110208201;    SECONDARY
```

I want a subset of the file where the first two characters of "SCHCD" is "13". So my subset (call it `outfile.txt`) should look like:

```
SCHCD;  SCHNAME
13110208001;    GOVT MIDSCHOOL 
13110208201;    SECONDARY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk ' NR == 1 || /^13/ ' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: Many thanks, Wes. Worked perfectly. What if the "13" were in the second column instead of right at the beginning?

Comment: @user702432: `awk ' NR == 1 || $2 ~ /^13/ ' infile.txt > outfile.txt`

Comment: Yes, I do. If I understand it correctly, your code is treating infile.txt as a flat file with no requirement for delimiting (which is perfect okay for my present problem). What I mean is what if I had to substring on the 2nd column? Just trying to increase my own knowledge-base. Thanks.

Comment: @user702432: `awk -F; ' NR == 1 || $2 ~ /^13/ ' infile.txt > outfile.txt ` - Now fixed. For the first column, we don't need to consider the delimiter.